# Using Handlebars.js to iterate over a list of names

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a Bootstrap select dropdown, and I'm attempting to use Handlebars JS to output the desired options into my selection, but they aren't appearing. I've read some examples here so not sure what is stopping my code from correctly rendering, any pointers would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" onChange="takeSelectedSourceValue(this);">
  <option id="source-language" value="" selected disabled>Auto</option>
  
  <div id="myForm"></div>
  <script type="text/handlebar-template" id="selectPersonTemplate">
  {{#each people}}
    <option value="{{valueLang}}">{{htmlLang}}</option>
  {{/each}}
  </select>
  </script>

 <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/handlebars.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    // Define an array of people.
  var people = [
    { valueLang: 'DE', htmlLang: 'DE' },
    { valueLang: 'FR', htmlLang: 'FR' },
    { valueLang: 'IT', htmlLang: 'IT' },
    { valueLang: 'ES', htmlLang: 'ES' },
    { valueLang: 'SV', htmlLang: 'SV' },
    { valueLang: 'DA', htmlLang: 'DA' }
  ];
  
  // Get the text for the Handlebars template from the script element.
  var templateText = $("#selectPersonTemplate").html();
  
  // Compile the Handlebars template.
  var selectPersonTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateText);
  
  // Evaluate the template with an array of people.
  var html = selectPersonTemplate({ people: people });
  
  // Take the HTML that was created with the Handlebars template and
  // set the HTML in the myForm div element.
  $("#myForm").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your HTML.

First, your closing select tag, `</select>` is within your template script tag.

What is within your script tag is ignored by the HTML parser because you have defined the script as `type="text/handlebar-template"`. Therefore, the parser does not see a closing select tag.

Second, `<div>` elements are not valid children of select, `<select>`, elements.

I am not sure if all browsers handle this invalid tag the same way, but I am trying it using Chrome and it seems that Chrome is completely ignoring the `<div id="myForm"></div>` when rendering. So there is no element to which to add the `html` produced by your template function. The `html` value should be *appended* to the `<select>`.

I would advise taking the template `<script>` tag out from within the `<select>`, just for clarity. This will make the HTML easier to read and clearly separate the `<select>` menu from the template.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" onChange="takeSelectedSourceValue(this);">
  <option id="source-language" value="" selected disabled>Auto</option>
</select>
  
<script type="text/handlebar-template" id="selectPersonTemplate">
  {{#each people}}
    <option value="{{valueLang}}">{{htmlLang}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Next, we want to be sure to *append* `html` to our `#inputGroupSelect01`  element.

```
// append the HTML to the #inputGroupSelect01 select element.
$("#inputGroupSelect01").append(html);
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ckm1uxv6/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer form Steve is perfectly fine and his fiddle also works fine. I would like to add some comments though and simplify the result:

About the closing tag `</select>`: Whenever you want to extend your existing HTML with Handlebars rendered HTML, you need to start with a **valid** HTML. In your case the browser already rendered the "invalid" `<select>` (invalid because the closing tag was missing). Most browsers then try to fix this by adding the closing tag,... but with your template you tried to add another one, and this doesn't work. I can see why you did this as you wanted to "complete" the `<select>` tag within your template, but this was too late already as the tag was rendered before your template got a chance to do so.

**Conclusion**: before your javaScript kicks in, the HTML is already rendered, even though it might be invalid HTML, so you need to make sure that it is valid before you manipulate the DOM.

The rest of what was going on (or wrong) was described by Steve...

To keep things simple I would probably even add the whole `<select>` inside the template so you need less references to HTMLElements and avoid complexity:

```
<script type="text/handlebar-template" id="selectPersonTemplate">
  <select class="custom-select" onChange="takeSelectedSourceValue(this);">
    <option id="source-language" value="" selected disabled>Auto</option>
    {{#each people}}
      <option value="{{valueLang}}">{{htmlLang}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</script>
```

and then the JS (only parts of the JS from the fiddle):

```
  // Get the template for Handlebars.
  // Put whole <select> inside template to keep things simple
  var template = $("#selectPersonTemplate");

  // Compile the Handlebars template.
  var selectPersonTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template.html());

  // Evaluate the template with an array of people.
  var html = selectPersonTemplate({ people: people });

  // Two ways of attaching the HTML to the DOM
  // $(html).insertAfter(template);
  template.replaceWith(html); // removes script at the same time
```

By just looking at the template and the code you might realise that everything seems to be clear and simple and not spread around any more.

Here the [slightly changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s6rpv50/2/) from Steve.